# nginx and mailman: forward to listinfo by default

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, mailman

I struggle now for quite a bit with the problem to get mailman and nginx running. Everything works fine but if the user vists just the domain, i get a HTTP 502 error.

How can i say nginx that it should use /listinfo as the default location? I can not specifiy it via the `try_files $uri /listinfo` in the `location /` section because then every site is forwarded to /listinfo. Somehow this does not work well with cgis...

This is my current config:

```
server {
    listen [::]:80;
    root /usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/;

    location = /mailman/listinfo {
        rewrite ^ /listinfo permanent;
    }

    location / {
        fastcgi_split_path_info (^/[^/]*)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
    }
    location /images/mailman {
        alias /usr/share/images/mailman;
    }
    location /pipermail {
        alias /var/lib/mailman/archives/public;
        autoindex on;
    }
}
```

Can i define a location to match an url like `http://example.com/` (without any parameter given)?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding a rule that matches only `/`:

```
location = / { 
    rewrite ^ /listinfo permanent;
}
```

if anyone has a better solution please post it!